# Execute aspect advice in same transaction context

Tags: spring-aop, aspect

I am trying to use Spring-AOP/AspectJ on the methods in a class annotated with @Transactional. So, I have two model DAO classes like this:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class ModelDAO {

public void save() {

}

}

@Transactional
@Repository
public class AnotherModelDAO {

public void save() {

}

}
```

And then an Aspect like:

```
@Aspect
public class ModelAspect {
@Around("publicMethod() && isModelClassSaveCalled()")
  public Object doAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    joinPoint.proceed();
    anotherModelDAO.save(); 
  }
}
```

So, my question is: Is it possible to call model.save() and anotherModel.save() to be called in same transaction context through aspect as mentioned above?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: short answer yes as long as `AnotherModelDAO` is injected into `ModelAspect` as regular spring bean :

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond +1 for your username!